# JW Player : execute javascript when logo is clicked

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I use JW Player.

I would like to execute a javascript function which load a DHTML Pop when you click on the logo.

Here my config :

```
jwplayer("videoplayer").setup({
    flashplayer: '/inc/player.swf',
    file: 'video.flv',
    logo:{
       file: 'logo.png',
       hide: 'false',
       position: 'bottom-right',
       linktarget: '_self',
       margin: '10',
       over: '1',
       out:'0.8',
    },
    provider:'http',        
    wmode: 'transparent',
    height: 534,
    width: 712,
    controlbar: 'bottom',
    autostart: true,
    mute: false,
    volume: 40,
    stretching: 'fill',
    backcolor: '000000',
    lightcolor: 'fad3e4',
    frontcolor: 'fad3e4',
    screencolor: '000000'
```

});

The function is contained on an external JS file.
Usually, i use this function in an a href like this :

```
<a href="javascript:inko_popdhtml_normal_clic.afficher();">text here</a>
```

Have a solution ?
Thank you.

Regards.
Aurélien.

Comment: [tag:logo] is a programming language tag at SO. If you think referring to graphical logo is essential, add [tag:graphical-logo].

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to know how to use that function when the logo is clicked, which you usually do with href. I know 2 ways to do it:

Either use a onClick attribut on your ellement, for example

```
<img src="logo" onClick="inko_popdhtml_normal_clic.afficher();">
```

or use JQuery:

```
$('your logo's element id').click(function(){
    inko_popdhtml_normal_clic.afficher();
}
```

Comment: Hello, i woulkd like to use the function in the logo on JW PLAYER :)

Answer (score 0):

An older topic but found this while I was searching for this same solution myself. This is a function in  the JWplayer video player where you can add a watermark to an image and add a link to the image. To make the image link to a javascript function it would be:

```
logo:{
    file: 'logo.png',
    link: 'javascript:functionHere()'
}
```